# Mount an only FTPS reachable storage?

Tags: ftps

I recently purchased a domain that comes with 10 GByte storage. I could be only reachable with FTP over TLS.

Are there any methods to "mount" this storage like when e.g.: using SSHFS?

Comment: I found it!! - CurlFtpFS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases; yes.   However this is achieved through software (usually run in userspace) and sometimes can cost money.

Since you didn't nail down what client-operating system, here's the broad ones.

Windows / OSX : http://www.expandrive.com/   Expandrive can "mount" a FTP(SSL) & sFTP drive just like a USB storage device.

Linux: CurlFtpFS should be able to mount it with FUSE.